# Semi-rounded rectangle with css

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if is there's a way to do the following rectangle's borders with border-radius or any other property, take a look at what i need:

[image: rectangle-needed]

And so far this is what I have got using `border-radius`:

[image: mine-rectangle]

The rectangle at top was created with Wix, the other one is made with CSS and HTML. As you can see the borders as so different.

Is there a way to accomplish it?

Comment: simply use percentage ex: `border-radius: 20%`

Comment: Make your border-radius relative to the div's size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible as you can define each corner within the border radius value, which will then give you the shape you want, see below for a simple example and you can read more on how this works on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

```css
#rcorners {
  border-radius: 4em / 2em;
  background: #73AD21;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rcorners">Rounded corners!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, you want `border-radius: x/y` where x is the higher value for the corner your looking for

```css
.test {
        margin: auto;
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        border-radius: 30%/10%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the horizontal and the vertical radius by : `border-radius: 50px/20px;`

[image]

Look at this example :

```css
div.example {
    background-color: #6495ED;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50px/20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```